# HTTP LIVE STREAMING on Apache

Tags: apache, streaming

I Am Using An Ubuntu server with apache installed i have 3 diffrent bitrates:

```
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/128/_playList.m3u8
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/512/_playList.m3u8
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/2048/_playList.m3u8
```

in each directory there is segment.ts files with their bitrate

and this is my main m3u8 :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=128,RESOLUTION=128x69
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/128/_playList.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=512,RESOLUTION=512x277
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/512/_playList.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1240,RESOLUTION=2048x1109
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/2048/_playList.m3u8
```

but when i use this file to play my stream

```
http://mysite.local/Adaptive/_Adaptive.m3u8
```

the first m3u8 will be played even when i am using on local webserver and BANDWIDTH is more that 10mb

is there any modules i should install on apache ?